# Cannot add Capabilities to the cordova project?

Tags: cordova, configuration, windows-store-apps, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

How can you add capabilities to the windows 8 manifest, such as:

```
<Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
```

I've tried putting

```
<Capability Name="internetClientServer" />

<config-file target="package.appxmanifest" parent="/Package/Capabilities">
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
</config-file>
```

in the Cordova's root config.xml

And even putting a package.manifest in the /res/native/windows

Nothing seems to be working.  And I can't seem to find any documentation regarding this.  Is this a bug, or should I try writing a custom plugin and adding the capabilities there?

Comment: Like the question but not so fond of the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Found a way around it.

Write a plugin that does nothing (no javascript source files) but in the plugins.xml add:

```
<config-file target="package.appxmanifest" parent="/Package/Capabilities">
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
</config-file>
```

under the windows platform heading.